# writing coverage group within a class in a system verilog file returns error

Tags: code-coverage, system-verilog

I am writing a covergroup in my .sv file within a class that I am using for randomizing some inputs.I keep getting error :

> An embedded coverage group not instantiated in the 'new' method

Then i am calling the run_coverage function in my initial block. I am not sure about it.

```
covergroup cg_for_arrays(ref logic [7:0]array, input int min, int max);
  coverpoint cp_array
      {
        bins s = {min,max};
      }
endgroup

function void run_coverage();
cg_for_arrays = new(array1,1,255);
cg_for_arrays.sample();
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very clear. You are only allowed to construct a covergroup defined inside a class inside the constructor of that class. See section *19.4 Using covergroup in classes* in the SystemVerilog IEEE 1800-2012 LRM.

Comment: thanks ! I am pretty new to this and still learning. I called the sample method in the function run_coverage and then called this method in the initial block of my main testcase. the cover point inputs are NOT at the DUT level, but the testcase runs on DUT. Will thsi be reported as a class property based coverage ?